# Android - Add "Up Botton" for lower level activity with appcompat theme?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, up-button

I am following the starter android development guide and trying to add a up bottom for lower level activities. However, I get an null pointer error when executing 
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Is it because of my theme (appcompat created by Eclipse automatically) doesn't support this?

How can I resolve it? thanks!

Comment: Never mind - I think using getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); resolves it

Answer (score 0):

Using getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); solves it.